# Упаковка повторяющихся подряд символов во вложенные списки (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Нужно что бы программа принимающая символы на ввод, например:

```
w w w o r l d g g g g r e a t t e c c h e m g g p w w w z a z
```

выводила список следующего вида:

```
[['w', 'w', 'w'], ['o'], ['r'], ['l'], ['d'], ['g', 'g', 'g', 'g'], ['r'], ['e'], ['a'], ['t', 't'], ['e'], ['c', 'c'], ['h'], ['e'], ['m'], ['g', 'g'], ['p'], ['w', 'w', 'w'], ['z'], ['a'], ['z']]
```

Что нужно исправить в коде ниже что бы он работал так, как описано выше?

```python
def list_for_copied_letters(text):
    list_for_print = []
    list_letters = []
    for letters in range(1, len(text)):
        if text[letters] == text[letters - 1]:
            list_letters.extend(text[letters - 1])
        else:
            list_for_print.append(list_letters)
            list_letters = []
    print(list_for_print)

list_for_copied_letters((input() + " *").split(" "))
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Крайне желателен ответ с пояснениями

Answer (score 3):

Можно так:

```py
from itertools import groupby

text = "wwworldggggreattecchemggpwwwzaz"
res = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(text)]
print(res)
```

Вывод:

```
[['w', 'w', 'w'], ['o'], ['r'], ['l'], ['d'], ['g', 'g', 'g', 'g'], ['r'], ['e'], ['a'], ['t', 't'], ['e'], ['c', 'c'], ['h'], ['e'], ['m'], ['g', 'g'], ['p'], ['w', 'w', 'w'], ['z'], ['a'], ['z']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать и через регулярные выражения

```
import re
text = 'wwworldggggreattecchemggpwwwzaz'

pattern = re.compile(r'(.)\1*')
print([list(p.group()) for p in pattern.finditer(text)])
```

Вывод

```
[['w', 'w', 'w'], ['o'], ['r'], ['l'], ['d'], ['g', 'g', 'g', 'g'], ['r'], ['e'], ['a'], ['t', 't'], ['e'], ['c', 'c'], ['h'], ['e'], ['m'], ['g', 'g'], ['p'], ['w', 'w', 'w'], ['z'], ['a'], ['z']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def list_for_copied_letters(text):
    list_for_print = []
    list_letters = []
    for letters in range(len(text) - 1):
        if text[letters] != text[letters + 1]:
            list_letters.append(text[letters])
            list_for_print.append(list_letters)
            list_letters = []
        else:
            list_letters.append(text[letters])
    print(list_for_print)


list_for_copied_letters((input() + " *").split(" "))
```

Comment: Э-э-х, не уважаете вы автора вопроса - ["Крайне желателен ответ с пояснениями"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1305956/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-python3#comment2305616_1305956) :-D

Comment: @MaxU это и есть автор вопроса. Судя по ответу, это код из вопроса без изменений, то есть, по словам автора, не рабочий "как надо".  Отсюда вопрос: зачем этот "ответ"?

Comment: @strawdog ну почему, он работает "как надо" и с изменениями, просто написан сложнее чем нужно, через регулярные выражения (как написано в ответе выше) удобнее

Answer (score 0):

Решение в духе основной логики автора.
Реализация проще без использования range:

```
def list_for_copied_letters(text):
    list_for_print = []
    list_letters = []

    for i, character in enumerate(text):
        
        if character in list_letters or len(list_letters) == 0:
            list_letters.append(character)
        else:
            list_for_print.append(list_letters)
            list_letters = [character]

        if i == len(text) - 1:
            list_for_print.append(list_letters)

    return list_for_print


string = 'wwworldggggreattecchemggpwwwzaz'
print(list_for_copied_letters(text=string))
```